# Joining rows within the same dataset in r

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
df  <- data.frame(
status = c('foo','foo','bar', 'bar'), 
name = c("joe", "steve", "john","matt"),
cost = c(1,2,3,4)
)

df

   status  name cost
     foo   joe    1
     foo steve    2
     bar  john    3
     bar  matt    4
```

And i'd like to transform it so that each row that matches another one based in status is joined together with its corresponding row. So it should look like this:

```
       status    name.y  cost.y  name.x   cost.x
       foo       joe     1       steve    2
       bar       john    3       matt     4
```

I am trying to use a left_join like this:

```
df %>% 
  left_join(
    x = ., y = ., by = 'status')
  )
```

But the result I get is this:

```
  status cost.x name.x cost.y name.y
     foo      1    joe      1    joe
     foo      1    joe      2  steve
     foo      2  steve      1    joe
     foo      2  steve      2  steve
     bar      3   john      3   john
     bar      3   john      4   matt
     bar      4   matt      3   john
     bar      4   matt      4   matt
```

Comment: If you have the same number of rows for each 'status' value, for example, for ''foo" you have 2 rows - then this task can be solved by using simple "for" loop and etc. But if you have different number of rows, for example, 2 rows with status "foo", and 3 rows with status "bar" = you will have "float" number of spreading columns = that is not good

Answer (score 0):

This is an unelegant, hack-y answer, but if its coming out like this, you could just filter everything except 2nd out of every 4 rows from your result.

Comment: One could but that is a far from ideal solution and not very scalable.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(splitstackshape) 

df %>%
  group_by(status) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(paste(.,collapse=","))) %>%
  cSplit(colnames(.)[-1],",")
```

Output is:

```
   status name_1 name_2 name_3 cost_1 cost_2 cost_3
1:    bar   john   matt     NA      3      4     NA
2:    foo    joe  steve   Prem      1      2      5
```

Sample data:

```
df <- structure(list(status = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("bar", 
"foo"), class = "factor"), name = structure(c(1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 
4L), .Label = c("joe", "john", "matt", "Prem", "steve"), class = "factor"), 
    cost = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)), .Names = c("status", "name", "cost"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can put the 2 columns on each line in a `tibble`, then `spread` it and `unnest`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df$xy <- c("x","y")
df %>%
  transmute(status,name_cost=map2(name,cost,~tibble(name=.x,cost=.y)),xy) %>%
  spread(xy,name_cost) %>%
  unnest

#   status name cost name1 cost1
# 1    bar john    3  matt     4
# 2    foo  joe    1 steve     2
```

If you define `df` with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` you can use this one liner, but careful with the resulting structure:

```
aggregate(cbind(name,cost) ~ status,df,identity)
#   status name.1 name.2 cost.1 cost.2
# 1    bar   john   matt      3      4
# 2    foo    joe  steve      1      2
```